# Minimal polynomial of a graph

Tags: algebraic-graph-theory, minimal-polynomials, adjacency-matrix

I would like to know why the minimal polynomial of a graph $G$ is $m(x) = \prod(x-λ_i)$ where the product is taken over all distinct eigenvalues $λ_i$.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the adjacency matrix of an undirected graph is symmetric, thus diagonalizable. That means that every irreducible factor of minimal polynomial has multiplicity one.